# ArcMap Building detection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, feature-extraction

Utilizing only ArcMap 10, is there a way to set up a tool that will automatically detect building footprints from aerial imagery and then build a polygon on them?

It doesn't need to be incredibly accurate, but something fast and automated would help. I have no idea where to even start working on such a thing using Python, if its even possible.

Comment: detecting it from what? An aerial raster?

Comment: using lidar data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for an efficient way of digitizing building footprints using orthophotos and ArcGIS 10](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30012/looking-for-an-efficient-way-of-digitizing-building-footprints-using-orthophotos)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the data you're working with, you can set up training sites to do a   ["Supervised Classification"](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/image-classification/what-is-image-classification-.htm) to extract  roof lines based on their spectral signature.  You'll need the Spatial Analyst extension, though.

It will kick out a raster image that you'll have to convert to polygons.